# Are there any tools can build object from text directly, like google protocol buffer?

Tags: python, orm, protocol-buffers

At most log process systems, log file is tab separated text files, the schema of the file is provided separately.
for example.

```
12 tom tom@baidu.com
3 jim jim@baidu.com
```

the schema is

```
id : uint64
name : string
email : string
```

In order to find record like this *person.name == 'tom'* ， The code is

```
for each_line in sys.stdin:
  fields = each_line.strip().split('\t')
  if feilds[1] == 'tom':  # magic number
    print each_line
```

There are a lot of magic numbers 1 2 3.

**Are there some tools** like google protocol buffer(It's for binary), So we can build the object from text directly?

```
Message Person {
  uint64 id = 1;
  string name = 2;
  string email = 3;
}
```

so we than build person like this: person = lib.BuildFromText(line)

```
for each_line in sys.stdin:
  person = lib.BuildFromText(each_line) # no magic number
  if person.name == 'tom':
    print each_line
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import csv

Person = {
    'id': int,
    'name': str,
    'email': str    
}

persons = []
for row in csv.reader(open('CSV_FILE_NAME', 'r'), delimiter='\t'):
    persons.append({item[0]: item[1](row[index]) for index, item in enumerate(Person.items())})
```

Answer (score 0):

How does lib.BuildFromText() function suppose to know how to name fields? They are just values in the line you pass to it, right? Here is how to do it in Python:

```
import sys
from collections import namedtuple
Person = namedtuple('Person', 'id, name, email')
for each_line in sys.stdin:
    person = Person._make(each_line.strip().split('\t'))
    if person.name == 'tom':
        print each_line
```

Comment: Thanks, It works. But this method doesn't have type check. If the record is 'ABC tom tom@baidu.com', The id column is wrong, But we doesn't check it. @cabaunga